# Place trace flags in bulk on selected features

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geometric-network, utility-network

I'm working on our company's geometric network looking for disconnected features. I have 102 purchase stations that I'm needing to trace from and was wondering if there was a quick way to select all and place flags on them?

I know I could run the Trace Geometric Network tool from toolbox, but I'd rather use the utility network analyst toolbar since the drawing method works quicker than a selection.

I've found some old threads where I'd have to write some code, but they weren't in python, and I'm not a strong programmer.

Comment: Where were these old "threads"?  Potential answerers are always more likely to be interested in providing quick help when all the information is present in the question rather than them needing to go looking for it.